# Validate xml with xsd in x++

Tags: xml, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I want to validate my xml against xsd in AX2009.
But whatever I change in the xml, the xml will always validate...
Wat is wrong with my code?

```
static void Job174(Args _args)
{
    XMLDocument                 xmlDocument;
    XMLSchema                   xmlSchema;
    XMLSchemaValidationError    validationError;
    XMLReader                   xmlReader;
    FileName                    xsdFile;
    ;

    xsdFile = 'c:\\e\\note.xsd';
    xmlSchema   = xmlSchema::newFile(xsdFile);
    if(xmlSchema)
    {
        //xmlDocument = new XMLDocument();
        //xmlDocument.load('c:\\e\\note.xml');
        xmlReader = XMLReader::newXml('c:\\e\\note.xml');

        validationError = xmlReader.validate(xmlSchema.writeToString());
        if (validationError)
          info(strfmt('%1',checkFailed(validationError.message())));
        else
          info('XML is Ok..!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to answer without the files. Most likely there are errors in your XSD file.

Comment: `'c:\\e\\note.xml'` could be changed to `@'c:\e\note.xml'`

Answer (score 1):

You used newXml instead of newFile on the xmlReader object.

I tried this code and works fine.

```
static void XMLValidateExample(Args _args) 
{
    XMLSchema                   xmlSchema;
    XMLSchemaValidationError    validationError;
    XMLReader                   xmlReader;
    FileName                    xsdFile;
    ;

    xsdFile = @"C:\Users\c.paz\Desktop\ari.xsd";
    xmlSchema   = xmlSchema::newFile(xsdFile);

    if(xmlSchema)
    {
        xmlReader = XMLReader::newFile(@"C:\Users\c.paz\Desktop\ARRENDAMIENTO OCC-error.xml");
        validationError = xmlReader.validate(xmlSchema.writeToString());

        if (validationError)
            info(strfmt('%1',checkFailed(validationError.message())));
        else
            info('XML is Ok..!');
    }
}
```

Best regards!